# how to serialize js object with avro schema that contains optional values

Tags: javascript, avro

I don't manage to serialize a simple js object with an avro schema and I don't understand why. The issue starts with the union types ["null", "float"]. It works when the value is null but not when it's a number.

How do I get this to work?

**schema**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "incoming_telemetry",
  "doc": "Telemetry message from herby device",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "deviceId", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "timestamp", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "waterTableRange", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "batteryCapacity", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "batteryCurrent", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "solarVoltage", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "batteryVoltage", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "temperature", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "wifiStrength", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "flowRate", "type": ["null", "float"]},
    {"name": "dummy", "type": ["null", "float"]}
  ]
}
```

**script**

```js
const avro = require('avro-js');
const schema = avro.parse('publishToAnalytics/incoming_telemetry_v1.0.avsc')
const data = {
    deviceId: 'test',
    timestamp: new Date().toDateString(),
    waterTableRange: 1.1,
    batteryCapacity: 2.2,
    batteryCurrent: 3.3,
    solarVoltage: 4.4,
    batteryVoltage: 5.5,
    temperature: 6.6,
    wifiStrength: 7.7,
    flowRate: 8.8,
};
const dataBuffer = schema.toBuffer(data)
```

**error**

```
Uncaught Error Error: invalid ["null","float"]: 1.1
    at throwInvalidError (/home/marc/coding/boum/iot/node_modules/avro-js/lib/schemas.js:2204:9)
    at UnionType._write (/home/marc/coding/boum/iot/node_modules/avro-js/lib/schemas.js:803:7)
    at writePet (<eval>/VM46947624:5:82)
    at Type.toBuffer (/home/marc/coding/boum/iot/node_modules/avro-js/lib/schemas.js:259:8)
    at <anonymous> (/home/marc/coding/boum/iot/publishToAnalytics/publishToAnalytics.js:16:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the library `avsc` instead of `avro-js` solves the problem. No need to change the rest of the code.

```
const avro = require('avsc');
```